# Xcode 7 ENABLE_BITCODE error is already YES, but still get's error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, bitcode

I've been searching and searching, and tried a lot of diffrent solutions from in here, but nothing helped so far.

I'm using Unity(newest version), and when i build my project in Xcode, i get this:
[image: pic 1]

I've tried to set Bitcode to NO, both on Project and Target. When i set i to NO on just one of them, or both, i get 15 to 25 new errors. 
As you can see here:
[image]

Is it because the architecture is arm64 in Unity? or what's the problem?
I can't seem to get this problem fixed, no matter how i switch between YES and NO on the Bitcode option.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with setting bitcode to `YES`; the issue is that you've set it to `YES` but that library (`libChartboost.a`) doesn't support it.  The other error is completely unrelated.

Comment: oh.. Well that explains a lot. I'll try see if i can find and update for the lib. Thanks a lot, helped me move forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to – @trojanfoe Mar 30 at 10:47
*"It's got nothing to do with setting bitcode to YES; the issue is that you've set it to YES but that library (libChartboost.a) doesn't support it. The other error is completely unrelated."*